# Is here any easy way how to set account validity for specific time in openldap?

Tags: openldap

I'm solving problem with openldap. My goal is by creating account in openldap also set a time, for how long is this account valid. So, after this time is expired, ldap return that this account don't exist/is no longer valid for example. I was googling, but didnt find anything what looks easy to implement. Am I only blind or is here really nothing like that?

Thanks all for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an overlay for this. It is called "dds"/"Dynamic Directory Services". You can find further information here: http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Dynamic%20Directory%20Services

Additionally, there is also a man page: man 5 slapo-dds :)

You can enable it by using cn=config by adding it as a new note, for example this way:

`dn: olcOverlay=dds,olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDDSConfig
olcOverlay: dds
olcDDSstate: TRUE
olcDDSmaxTtl: 604800
olcDDSminTtl: 86400
olcDDSdefaultTtl: 86400
olcDDSinterval: 3600
olcDDStolerance: 0
olcDDSmaxDynamicObjects: 10`

In this case `olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config` is the database which represents your DIT (Data Information Tree, your main LDAP directory). Check the node's `olcSuffix` attribute to be sure.

Once this overlay is enabled, you can create a new node in your DIT and add the auxiliary object class `dynamicObject`; this way your new node has the specified life time.

Example:

`dn: cn=user1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: person
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: dynamicObject
cn: user1
userPassword: password`

This overlay becomes even more powerfull once combined with the memberOf-overlay (`man 5 slapo-memberof`). Be sure to check it out!

Comment: Hi, sorry for late reply, but can you please be more specific? I'm still not so familiar wiyh OpenLDAP, so I don't know what/where/how add/change according your advice. Thanks

Comment: Please read yourself into configuration of OpenLDAP using `cn=config`. A possible source of information is the LDAP tutorial on the zytrax website. Once you get the hang of it, you will know how to add an overlay. And once you add the DDS overlay, the rest will become pretty obvious :)